# preg_match to sanitize input for the best security

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I am working on a wordpress website (i am new to web development). I installed a theme and now I am looking to improve it and make it suit my needs. Regarding the register form, the theme's code to check for invalid characters in the password is this:

```
else if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9@#-_$%^&+=!?]{1,20})$/", $data['user_password'])==0) {
                SendtoUSER::$messages[]=__('Forbidden characters detected', 'mytheme');
```

and for the username is this

```
if(preg_match('/[@\s]/', $username)) {
            $valid=false;
        }
```

I did some research and i understand most of the expression `"/^([a-zA-Z0-9@#-_$%^&+=!?]{1,20})$/"` - what i don't get is why ; is still valid to use (i observed that removing `#-_`prevents `;` from working, so is `#-_` an inverval?) My question is what `@#-_$%^&+=!?` means in the expression? Is this code good enough, what are some good practices to implement preg_match for max security? Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: "what are some good practices to implement preg_match for max security?" Don't. Limiting the characters in a password **reduces** security.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Also, I am afraid of malformated strings :)

Comment: I agree with @ceejayoz that you should never bother to limit the user's use of characterset in a password but rather impose a minimal lower-bound on password length. So don't use a password less than 8 characters is a good practice. Use a password no-more than 20 characters, however, is a bad one. Also the key to security in secrets is predictability so most sites offer some form of cardinality indicator to perserve the user's perspective on how secure their password is. So see something like [password meter](http://www.passwordmeter.com/) as an example.

Comment: @VreauCutitul Malicious password strings shouldn't matter, because they're never displayed, and they're stored as a hash (using the `password_hash` function), not their original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in WordPress, the `sanitize_text_field` will be the best solution to do it. You can validate it:

```
if ( sanitize_text_field( $data['user_password'] ) !== $data['user_password']  ) {
    $valid=false;
}
```

Also, I've checked how it works on the Profile page, and it looks like in the core, it validates as:

```
$pass1 = trim( $_POST['pass1'] );
//...
// Check for "\" in password.
if ( false !== strpos( wp_unslash( $pass1 ), '\\' ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'pass', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Passwords may not contain the character "\\".' ), array( 'form-field' => 'pass1' ) );
}
```

Probably the best solution is copying the WordPress solution as well.